# Is there a more improved declarative view technology than JSTL with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I wanted to use JSTL and JSP tags with spring mvc but it seems to lack more declarative constructs.  E.g. it would be nice to just bind a 'list' to a type of listview and that get rendered as a list of items.  I believe spring, form elements and other widgets are OK but using JSTL seems lacking because it is very procedural.  For example foreach, if constructs leads to sloppy code.

Also, it would be nice if there is view add-on with Spring that might even have default styling, listview functions like swapping style between odd and even.  Basic pagination support?

We won't be able to use JSF.

Comment: Wicket or any of the other component based frameworks.

Comment: I still wanted to keep the architecture.   Some kind of tag library and spring mvc.  Nobody has really come up with this yet?  Say if you wanted to keep with your JSP pages.  Is there  non JSTL tag library out there?

Comment: I guess you want something fancier than jqGrid?  Cause jqGrid and Apache Tiles is way cool in my book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Spring and JSF and PrimeFaces offers the UI support as I asked in my original question including a large set of ajax widgets and other features.